# При наведении ничего не происходит

Tags: html, css

При наведении ничего не происходит

```
.u-p1 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 82.5%;
  height: 41px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.u-p1 a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  padding-left: 27px;
}

.left {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 41px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  right: -33%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  
}

.left a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  padding-left: 27px;
}


.u-p1 .left :hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: `.left:hover` — без пробела

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME так же не работает

Comment: @КаринаОлдова, не может не работать. Приложите минимальный воспроизводимый пример

Comment: @Voprositel вместе с курсором не скринется

Comment: нужен кусок html кода с этими элементами. найти ошибку опытным путем )

Answer (score 1):

```css
.u-p1 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 82.5%;
  height: 41px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.u-p1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 27px;
}

.left {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 41px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  right: -33%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.left a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 27px;
}

.u-p1:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="u-p1">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```